# How to get the seconds difference between now() and TimeStamp with microseconds (2020-10-06T08:52:54.3556219Z) and using Java 8?

Tags: date, time, java-8, response, difference

I wanted to calculate the difference between the current time and timestamp in microseconds (2020-10-06T08:52:54.3556219Z) that I received in the response using Java 8, please advise. I have used the following and I didn't get anything concrete solution, hence asking here!

1. LocalDateTime
2. ZonedDateTime
3. SimpleDateFormat

Comment: You should use `Instant`.

Comment: I have already tried Instant and retried again as below, hope its correct:                                                
        `timestamp = Instant.parse(payload.getTimestamp());//2020-10-06T10:05:45.027416200Z
        now_timestamp = Instant.now();//2020-10-06T10:05:45.034Z
        diffInNanos = Math.abs(now_timestamp.compareTo(timestamp)); // NANO SECONDS
        diffInMicros = diffInNanos / 1000; // MICRO SECONDS
        diffInMillis = diffInMicros / 1000; // MILLI SECONDS
        diffInSeconds = diffInMillis / 1000; // SECONDS
        assertThat(diffInSeconds < acceptableLimit)`

Comment: Finally, the diffInSeconds value was in the above said example was '0.0065837996'.

Comment: `compareTo` is not specified to give you a difference. You can use `Instant.parse("2020-10-06T08:52:54.3556219Z").until(Instant.now(), ChronoUnit.SECONDS)`, for example.

Comment: How can I parse the 'Tue, 06 Oct 2020 13:42:02 GMT' into Instant?

Comment: `new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z").parse(restResponse.getHeaders().get("Date").getValue()).toInstant()` worked,hope this is one of the right ways.

Comment: Try to avoid outdated `SimpleDateFormat`, use `DateTimeFormatter` of _java.time_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Instant` and call `.getEpochSecond()` to get the seconds then calculate difference in second

```
Instant dateTime = Instant.parse("2020-10-06T10:05:45.027416200Z");     
Instant nowDateTime = Instant.now(); // 2020-10-06T10:44:23.173333200Z
long diffSeconds = nowDateTime.getEpochSecond() - dateTime.getEpochSecond();
```

Output: `2318`